# how to get the current location latitude and longitude of android mobile device?

Tags: android, location, latitude-longitude

I have implemented sample application for get the current location latitude longitude.If i lunch my application in emulator and i am sending latitude and longitude from Emulator Controls at eclipse then i am getting current location latitude and longitude which from emulator controls.If i lunch the same application in real device then i am not able to get current location latitude and longitude

I have implemented code for get the current location latitude and longitude as follows:

```
      LocationManager mlocManager = (LocationManager)getSystemService(Context.LOCATION_SERVICE);

  LocationListener mlocListener = new MyLocationListener();
  mlocManager.requestLocationUpdates(LocationManager.GPS_PROVIDER, 11, 11, mlocListener);


   public class MyLocationListener implements LocationListener
{

  @Override
  public void onLocationChanged(Location loc)
  {

    loc.getLatitude();
    loc.getLongitude();

   Log.v("11111","Latitude :"+loc.getLatitude());
   Log.v("22222","Longitude :"+ loc.getLongitude());

    }
```

}

From the above code i am not getting current location latitude and longitude in real android device.

How can i get current location latitude and longitude of real device?

please any body help me

Comment: have you getting any error ?? if yes then post logcat of that

Comment: no i am not getting any error.but i am getting nothing

Comment: because when u are running this app on device at that u have change ("GPS_PROVIDER")  to ("NETWORK_PROVIDER"). so after this u will get output...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

prasad try this code ..by using this i am successfully getting lat long

```
        private Location location = null;
        private LocationManager locationManager = null;
    locationManager = (LocationManager) context.getSystemService                              (Context.LOCATION_SERVICE);

    Criteria locationCritera = new Criteria();
    locationCritera.setAccuracy(Criteria.ACCURACY_FINE);
    locationCritera.setAltitudeRequired(false);
    locationCritera.setBearingRequired(false);
    locationCritera.setCostAllowed(true);
    locationCritera.setPowerRequirement(Criteria.NO_REQUIREMENT);

    String providerName = locationManager.getBestProvider(locationCritera,
            true);
    location = locationManager.getLastKnownLocation(providerName);
    locationListener = new MyLocationListener();

    locationManager.requestLocationUpdates(LocationManager.GPS_PROVIDER, 0,
            0, locationListener);

    currentLocation = context.getSharedPreferences(PREFS_NAME, 0);
    editor = currentLocation.edit();
}
public String getCurrentLatitude() {
    try {
        if (!currentLocation.getString("currentLatitude", "")
                .equalsIgnoreCase(""))
            return currentLocation.getString("currentLatitude", "");
        else if (location.getLatitude() != 0.0)
            return Double.toString(location.getLatitude());
        else
            return "0.0";
    } catch (Exception e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
    return "0.0";
}

public String getCurrentLongitude() {
    try {


        if (!currentLocation.getString("currentLongitude", "")
                .equalsIgnoreCase(""))
            return currentLocation.getString("currentLongitude", "");
        else if (location.getLongitude() != 0.0)
            return Double.toString(location.getLongitude());
        else
            return "0.0";
    } catch (Exception e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
    return "0.0";
}
```

Comment: make sure that gps is enabled in device

Comment: Code of MyLocationListener() class

Answer (score 4):

GPS_PROVIDER does not work in bound place. So if gps_provider is enabled but you get null location you can replace provider from gps to NETWORK_PROVIDER.

Answer (score 1):

are you trying on emulator or device. if you are trying in device then your device should have to be near window or in open place.

Comment: i am trying on my real device in my lab.isn't it work in my lab?This is not an answer it is comment.plz don't post it as answer.

Comment: It can be answer in a guidebase dear. I wanted to know why you are getting error.  are you trying it in open place ?

Answer (score 1):

override these methods in your MyLocationListener. so that you can track your GPS status. check and see if you can get whats the problem

```
public void onProviderDisabled(String provider)

        {

            Toast.makeText( getApplicationContext(),"Gps Disabled",

                    Toast.LENGTH_SHORT ).show();

        }

        public void onProviderEnabled(String provider)

        {

            Toast.makeText( getApplicationContext(),"Gps Enabled",Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();

        }

        public void onStatusChanged(String provider, int status, Bundle extras)

        {

        }
```

Answer (score 1):

On a real device, you will have to be patient and wait for a fix from the satellites. This can take several minutes, even with a clear view of the sky.

For testing outside, you would be better advised to have a simple text box in your app, initialise it to something like "No GPS fix yet", then send a string comprised of the lat/long coordinates to it when the location changes.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe this is more clear. I will change the conditional to something more efficient later if it is possible

```
    double longitude = 0;
    double latitude = 0;

    LocationManager lm = (LocationManager) getSystemService(Context.LOCATION_SERVICE);
    if (lm.getLastKnownLocation(LocationManager.GPS_PROVIDER) != null) {
        Location location = lm
                .getLastKnownLocation(LocationManager.GPS_PROVIDER);
        longitude = location.getLongitude();
        latitude = location.getLatitude();
    } else {
        Location location = lm
                .getLastKnownLocation(LocationManager.NETWORK_PROVIDER);
        longitude = location.getLongitude();
        latitude = location.getLatitude();
    }
```